# Should I flag duplicate comments?

Tags: support, flags, declined-flags

The discussed comments are for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16312528/check-if-an-array-contains-any-element-of-another-array-in-javascript/25926600#25926600). As you can see, Paul Grimshaw has suggested

> event tidier like this: `arr.some(v=> haystack.indexOf(v) >= 0)`

(most likely "event" should be "even") and several months later webjay proposed

> in one line `arr1.some(v => arr2.indexOf(v) >= 0)`

I've flagged the second comment as "something else" with the following comment:

> duplicates what Paul Grimshaw proposed in another comment

Now, the flag [got declined](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/3995261?group=4&status=3) and I wonder why. The flagged comment doesn't really bring anything new and I consider it as "noise" just like those "thank you" comments. Am I missing something?

Comment: Side note: don't use custom flags for this (which require more effort than it's worth). Just flag as "no longer needed".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is they're not obvious duplicates because the second one changes up the arguments some. Worse, you're having to fight uphill on this because

1. The comment is likely shown without context (a lot of mortal mod tools commit this sin)
2. You're expecting a mod to know enough JS to tell they're making the same argument

I think it's the latter that did you in. There's a decline reason for that

> flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

This isn't a wrong comment, it just restates a previous comment. This is a common problem on canonicals. You'll often see people posting "Me too" answers for free rep ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336858)). The comment, by contrast, really doesn't benefit the poster (upvtoed comments are cool and might get you a badge but that's it).

## TL;DR

Comments that are at least constructive can be left alone (there's no real benefit to the poster).

Comment: ok, this makes sense to some extent, pity that we don't know for sure what is shown to mods